# Send URL parameters in lowercase, and get them in their original case-formatting

Tags: php, case-sensitive, url-parameters

So I want to send URL parameters, which for example are something like:

`ParaMeter +1`, `ParaMeter +2`, `ParaMeter +3` and so on. As you can see they have spaces and different upper/lower case formatting. These parameters will be used to fill a form and I need them to be preserved as they are in the examples - with all of their current formatting.

I send them with:

```html
href="/page1/params/<?=urlencode($exampleArray['parameter'])?>/
```

and in the URL it is shown as `https://www.my-site.tld/page1/params/ParaMeter+%20+1/`

and I use `$_GET` to get them.

Which works fine, except, as I've read and researched, it is not a good practice to have an upper-case letters in your URL. I've tried with `strtolower()`, and it looks fine for the URL, but not for the form, since all of the characters are shown in lower-case and I need them to be in the same formatting as the examples. Is there a way preserve the formatting while they are lower-case in the URL? Also, I know that I could get them via a map (using an array), but in my case the amount of ParaMeter-s is a lot and will take as much time to create it.

Comment: '*Which works fine, except, as I've read and researched, it is not a good practice to have an upper-case letters in your URL.*' - *[citation needed]*

Comment: IMHO just forget about upper case being bad practice. Your only choice otherwise would be to have a list of parameters in upper case on the PHP side, and use it to reconstruct their values by using strtolower and comparision with the lowercase parameters in the `$_GET`

Comment: Nothing wrong with mixed case in URLs. Just use them as you need to.

Comment: @Script47 You'll find enough articles across the internet that touch on the topic of letter case in URLs. Most of them are centered around SEO and the idea that `/params` is different than `/Params` since the *path* part of a URL is case sensitive, hence search engines could consider these to be two different pages even if they serve the same content. The fact is, that this particular use case doesn't really fall into that category and the OP should be just fine using uppercase characters in your URLs. There are no specs that say using uppercase should be avoided or is outside the norm.

Comment: @Bogdan interesting. Wasn't aware of the SEO implications. I guess, it's as you mentioned, in this case OP might as well make use of the mixed case.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers. I guess you are right and I put a lot of thought into something, that is not that important. @Script47 unfortunately I cannot provide citation, but it was SEO related, as the other comments suggested.